# Access problem with consecutive CR-00000001

Tags: ms-access

I need this consecutive "CR-00000001" for every BILL.

So I created a cell with "NUMBER_CONSECUTIVE" with type text and "CONSECUTIVE" with the type calculated. And inside the element

```
CONSECUTIVE = "CR" + "-" + [NUMBER_CONSECUTIVE]
```

And in the form, the element number_consecutive have a event, where I put the code:

```
=Cint(DLast("NUMBER_CONSECUTIVE"; "FAC_BILL")) + 1
```

but is not working, and I am not sure is the right method.

Can you help me?, thanks.

Comment: Cell, inside, and Element are not known in Access; and which event are you using?

Comment: The 'code' looks like an expression in a textbox ControlSource. That will not save data to table field. Don't trust Last (or First) to pull desired value. Max may be what you should use. "Inside the element" means nothing in Access world.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a more robust way. More work, but more reliable. My solution would be:

Create a table `COUNTERS` with the following fields:

- `COUNTER_ID`. PK. Autonum
- `HEADER`. Text.
- `SERIAL`. Long.

You create a new record with `HEADER="CR"` and `SERIAL=0`.

Then, every time you want a new code for the bill, you call to the following function:

```
Public Function CREATE_SERIAL_CODE(lngCounterId As Long) As String
   
   On Error Goto CREATE_SERIAL_CODE_Err
   
    'Declaration
    Dim dbCurrDB As DAO.Database
    Dim rstCounters As DAO.Recordset

    Dim lngCounterId As Long
    Dim strHeader As String
    Dim lngSerial As Long
    Dim strSerialCode As String
   
    Dim strMessage As String
    Dim strCriterion As String
    
    'Initialization
    Set dbCurrDB = CurrentDB
    Set rstCounters = dbCurrDB.OpenRecordset("COUNTERS",2)
   
    lngCounterId=Nz(lngCounterId)
   
    'Initial Validations
    If lngCounterId=0 Then
        strMessage="Some warning"
        MsgBox strMessage, bla bla bla
        Set dbCurrDB=Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
   
    'Obtaining the geader and increasing the serial number
    With rstCounters
    
        strCriterion="COUNTER_ID=" & lngCounterId
        
        .FindFirst strCriterion
        
        If .NoMatch=True Then
            strMessage="Some warning"
            MsgBox strMessage, bla bla bla
            Set dbCurrDB=Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        'Obtain header and current serial number
        strHeader=!HEADER
        lngSerial=nz(!SERIAL)
        
        'Increase serial number
        lngSerial=lngSerial + 1
        
        'Write it on the table
        .Edit
            !SERIAL=lngSerial
        .Update
        
    End With
    
    'Constructing the serial code
    
    'Generate the necessary 0 (based on your example of a 8 digit serial)
    Select Case Len(Cstr(lngSerial))
        Case 1
            strSerialCode = "0000000" & lngSerial
        Case 2  
            strSerialCode = "000000" & lngSerial
        Case 3
            strSerialCode = "00000" & lngSerial
        Case 4
            strSerialCode = "0000" & lngSerial
        Case 5
            strSerialCode = "000" & lngSerial
        Case 6
            strSerialCode = "00" & lngSerial
        Case 7
            strSerialCode = "0" & lngSerial
        Case 8
            strSerialCode = "" & lngSerial
    End select
    
    'Attach the header
    strSerialCode = strHeader & "-" & strSerialCode
    
    CREATE_SERIAL_CODE = strSerialCode
    
    Set dbCurrDB = Nothign
    
    Exit Function
    
CREATE_SERIAL_CODE_Err:
    Set dbCurrDB = Nothign
    MsgBox Err.Description
    
End Function
```